# Vim slow performance when dealing with remote files

Tags: performance, vim

I'm opening a file on a remote drive - it takes 3-4 seconds to open it - that's ok.

But afterwards, a lot of commands become really slow.
I'm typing `:help vimrc` - it takes 3-4 seconds to display.
I'm typing `:setlocal nobuflisted` - it takes 3-4 seconds.

It probably has something to to with those commands accesing the filesystem. If I do `:setlocal list` it works ok. 
Also if I switch to another buffer, everthing is back to normal again.

Is there something I can do to improve performance?

Comment: Are you using Windows (also, which Vim `:version`)? Is this a Windows / Samba file server, or some other remote file system protocol?

Comment: yes I'm on windows (vim 7.3). The drive i'm accessing is just a remote network drive.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the swap file is created in the remote directory and slows down your performance.
Try setting the default directory for swap and backup files on your local drive with:

```
set directory=/home/john/tmp
set backupdir=/home/john/tmp
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your `'statusline'` setting and autocmds on events like `CursorMoved[I]` and `BufWinEnter`.

I once had a function in my status line that invoked `expand('%:p:h')`; it caused a noticeable slowness as experienced by you. I fixed this by caching the lookups in a script-local Dictionary.